# How to skip executing logic inside the event handler when it is executed from a particular Action

Tags: jquery

I click on the Addons Button and check some Toppings and Crustigs .

When i click on the Remove all Button , i am calling a funcion to uncheckall Checkboxes

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function (e) {
    $("#addonsWrap").find("label.ui-checkbox-on").click();
});
```

which in turn executing the ui-checkbox-on

My question is how can i skip the logic inside the below event when clikced from the Remove All

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-checkbox-on', function (event) {

}
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/15/

In simple how can i skip the alert inside the

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-checkbox-on', function (event) {

}
```

If it is from RemoveAll action

Comment: I am trying to use event.target , but i am getting empty http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/16/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try passing parameters to click event and then condition it based on that. 
Instead of `.click()` directly, use `trigger click` and send parameters to it as [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) takes args like this

> .trigger ( eventType [, extraParameters ] )

In your handlers for `ui-checkbox-off` and `ui-checkbox-on` you can check if there are any args they are receiving.

`$("#addonsWrap").find("label.ui-checkbox-on").trigger('click', [1]);`

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-checkbox-off', function (event, data) {
    if(data !== undefined) return;
    ....
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/cod7ceho/17/)

Hope this helps.